# Cursor position On the console need help on this code?

Tags: c++, c++11, console, cursor-position

how to change the position of the cursor ina loop. because on each `cin` it remains on the same position.. i have to move the curse in the middle of the console for each input.. how do i do it?

```
 int j;
 do{
     cout<<"Enter names"<<endl;
     got(24,40);
      j++;
    }while(j<4);
```

for changing the position of the cursor my function is

```
void gotoxy (short int x,short int y)
  {COORD cur={x,y}; SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),cur);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `gotoxy()` function before you call `cin`

Like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void gotoxy (short int x,short int y)
{COORD cur={x,y}; SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),cur);}



int main(void)
{

  int j=0;
  char input[32];
  string names[6];

     do{

         gotoxy(24,12);
         cout<<"                                                        ";
         gotoxy(24,12);
         cout<<" "<<j+1<<". Enter names > ";
         cin>>input;

         names[j]=string(input);
         j++;

       }while(j<4);

  cout<<"\n--  N a m e s  -- \n\n";
  for(int i=0;i<=j;i++) cout<<names[i]<<"  \n";

  cout<<"\n \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```